# Perl добавить чекбоксы в БД

Tags: mysql, sql, perl

Есть форма с множеством инпутов.

```
^[@items2 ^[$name] <input type=checkbox name=acc_^[$id] ?] > @]
```

ID много и заранее прописать каждый я не могу.

Пытаюсь взять отмеченные поля и добавить в БД.
Вот так:

```
foreach my $acct (param()) {
    if ($acct =~ /^acc_(\d+)$/ ) {           
            if (param($acct) =~ /^\d+$/ && param(&acct)->{selected}) {
             my $sth = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO catalog_chains (cidc, pidc) VALUES (?,?)");
             my $rvs = $sth->execute($id, param($acct)) or &error($sth->errstr);
            }  
        }
    }
```

Т.е. беру все с acc*, вытаскиваю оттуда только ID (без acc), проверяю на отмеченность и пытаюсь отмеченные добавить в БД.

Что я делаю не так?

Вот еще так попробовал.

```
foreach my $acct (param()) {
    if ($acct =~ /^acc_(\d+)$/ ) {           
         if (param($acct) =~ /^\d+$/) {
             my $sth = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO catalog_chains (cidc, pidc) VALUES (?,?)");
             my $rvs = $sth->execute($id, param($acct)) or &error($sth->errstr);

        }  

    }
}
```

Comment: Вы что то не договариваете. Видимо вы используете какую то библиотеку для работы с формой, о которой умолчали. Синтаксис примера инпута явно относится к какому то шаблониатору, о котором так же ни слова. И главное, что такое `param()`, что и в каком случае оно возвращает. Что за функция acct, вызываемая таким странным способом `param(&acct)`

Comment: Если бы я знал.... Такая админка на сайте досталась мне "в наследство". acct - это просто имя - ничего в себе не несет. Param(), как я думаю, это все поля формы. Берет все поля формы (обычная html), находит те поля, в которых в имени присутствует acc_  - выкидывает acc_ и заносит в БД только цифру после acc_

Comment: А что такое переменная $id ? я не вижу где она объявлена и что содержит. Я вижу только `/^acc_(\d+)$/` что занесет цифры после acc в `$1`, которая будет затерта в следующей же строке при выполнении `param($acct) =~ /^\d+$/`

Comment: Я очень плохо понимаю в perl. id берется из формы. С ним всё в порядке. Он добавляется. Но как бы я не писал скрипт, всегда там, где должна быть цифра после acc_ - заносится ноль. В принципе, все добавляется. Только вот этот acc_ - нуль всегда.

Comment: id в input и id в самом скрипте - разные. Но это не важно. Мне нужно именно этот acc_ вытащить.

Comment: вместо занесения в БД просто распечатайте значения $id, я подозреваю что там содержится 0. Потому что написанный код цифру после acc_ хоть и пытается выделить но тут же ее выбрасывает и нигде не использует

Comment: Да, так и получается - нуль. А как мне не выбрасывать? Разве = не знак присвоения? $acct =~ /^acc_(\d+)$/  - вот это вот?

Comment: А еще вы ни слова ни сказали о структуре БД. что должны содержать поля cidc и pidc ?

Comment: Подумал, что это лишняя информация. Решил не забивать топик водой. В БД только цифры. pidc int(1) UNSIGNED / cidc int(11)

Comment: Нет. присваивание `=`, а `=~` оператор сравнения с регулярным выражением, который только сравнивает значение в $acct с регуляркой. при этом он возвращает истину или ложь в зависимости от того, совпало или нет. При этом так как `\d` в круглых скобках то сразу после выполнения этого сравнения в переменной `$1` содержится как раз значение скобок. Возможно стоит написать в следующей строке `$id = $1;` что бы это значение попало в $id

Comment: под структурой БД я понимал не столько тип колонок, сколько пояснение какие именно значения они содержат, т.е. для чего используются

Comment: и очень рекомендую обратить внимание на param(&acct) я не предстваляю что он должен делать. Но что он точно делает, так это вызывает _функцию_ с именем acct (не имеющую никакого отношения к переменной $acct) и ее результат передает в param. может конечно оно так и задумано, но такие вещи надо контролировать

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95440/discussion-between-ysmhypno-and-mike).

Comment: Господи! Как же Вы мне помогли! Все что хотел - работает. Спасибо! А все дело в этой $1 - о которой я даже не знал.

Comment: Вам стоит почитать азы perl. Он в некоторых вопросах очень сильно отличается от других языков и когда смотришь со стороны, конечно все эти вещи про `$1`, отличие =~ от = и т.п. абсолютно не очевидны, потому что не имеют прямых аналогов в других языках. P.S. для ускорения работы настоятельно рекомендуется выполнять `my $sth = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO catalog_chains (cidc, pidc) VALUES (?,?)");` один раз, перед циклом foreach. А внутри оставить только `$sth->execute(...)`. Работать будет так же, но быстрее, так как запрос будет компилироваться только один раз